How to Display Blog Items in Rows Instead of Columns Using EJS and CSS?
I'm using this code to print out blogs on my site
<div class="blogView">
     <ol>
            <% if (locals.listaBlogova) { %>
                <% listaBlogova.forEach(function (blog) { %>
                    <li class="blog-item"><h1><%= blog.naslov %></h1><br>
                    <h3>Autor: <%= blog.autor %></h3><br>
                    <p><%= blog.tekst %></p></li>
                    <form action="/edit/<%= blog.id %>" method="get"> <input type="submit" value="EDIT" id=<% blog.id %>></form>
                    <form action="/delete/<%= blog.id %>" method="get"> <input type="submit" value="DELETE" id=<% blog.id %>></form>
                <%  }); %> 
            <% }; %> 
        </ol>
    </div>

I want to have 3 blogs in a row, but I can't get them to go in rows they always go in the first column underneath one another, i think the problem is the way I print them idk, could use some help.
I have tried using both grid and flex, nothing seems to work, so maybe its the problem in the way im priting them out.

You should really add your css to you question :)

You should check your HTML, it's not valid. The submit buttons for edit and delete are outside of the list item. Settings the <ol> to either display: grid; or display: flex; should work. If you want to use grid, which I would recommend, don't forget to set grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) to get 3 per row.
